# How to update from php 5.4.x to php 5.5 on ubuntu 12.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-5.5, php-5.4, ubuntu-12.10

I tried to update my php from 5.4.x to 5.5.x  with this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565784/how-do-i-upgrade-php-version-to-the-latest-stable-released-version). But it did not work.
my system claimed nothing to update and everything is newest.
Could someone help me???

Comment: This seems like more of a server thing then a scripting issue...

Comment: i tried to `apt-get clean` and make new folder `/var/lib/apt/list` too. But not work when i called `apt-get install php5.5`

Comment: I got `E: Unable to locate package php5.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php5.5'`

Comment: is there anyway to install php5.5  manually??